# wget application replacement

Tags: linux, wget, application

Is there any other application similar to wget?

If yes can you post a link?

Comment: Is there something wrong with wget that you're looking to find in another tool?

Comment: Not really. But the guys I work for said: "We don't want wget" (no reasons given). So... you get the picture.

Comment: I'd ask for reasons, because those reasons will probably apply to any replacement.

Comment: After 6 months of knowing them... I finally learned is useless to try get anything from them :).

Comment: Oof, that's no fun. Well, best of luck! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may look at [Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/). Quoted from Curl Website.

> curl is a tool to transfer data from
>   or to a server, using one of the
>   supported protocols (DICT, FILE, FTP,
>   FTPS, GOPHER, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP,
>   IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP,
>   RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS, TELNET
>   and TFTP). The command is designed to
>   work without user interaction.
>
> curl offers a busload of useful tricks
>   like proxy support, user
>   authentication, FTP upload, HTTP post,
>   SSL connections, cookies, file
>   transfer resume and more.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Just noticed someone else posted about Curl.

You can also use [lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/), [links](http://www.jikos.cz/~mikulas/links/) or [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/). They are browsers but can download files if you don't need anything complex and may get you out of trouble if you don't have anything else available.

Answer (score 2):

[Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) is the best downloading tool I know of, although for some applications wget is more suitable.

You can [see more alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/wget/) on alternativeto.net.